# looking for org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select jar path

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Can anyone help me to find the link of below jar

org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select

Comment: Where did you last see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you add selenium to your project and what IDE are you using?

If you downloaded the jars manually from the [selenium website](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) then they're here:
[image: manual jar]

They're in `client-combined-3.141.59.jar` and when you add it to your IDE you'll have the path you want.

However its not good practice to download and add them manually. You'll be stuck manually upgrading them and having trouble with remote execution.

It's much better if you use maven or gradle to manage this for you.

As one quick example, in maven you add this in you pom.xml:

```
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
```

It manages your dependencies for you. You get this in your project:
[image: maven dependencies managed]